# get all second highest from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, group-by, groupwise-maximum

I have a table with four fields as follows,

(UID is User ID)

```
ID UID MUSIC DATE 
1   0   a   2013-10-20
2   0   a   2013-10-21
3   0   a   2013-10-22
4   0   a   2013-10-24
5   0   b   2013-10-11
8   0   b   2013-10-15
10  0   c   2013-10-26
9   0   c   2013-10-25
7   0   c   2013-10-20
6   0   c   2013-10-18
11  0   d   2013-10-10
```

How can I retrieve all second highest date from above table using MySQL Query?

Expected result:

```
ID UID MUSIC DATE 
3   0   a   2013-10-22
5   0   b   2013-10-11
9   0   c   2013-10-25
```

or

```
ID UID MUSIC DATE 
3   0   a   2013-10-22
5   0   b   2013-10-11
9   0   c   2013-10-25
11  0   d   2013-10-10
```

Comment: what do you mean by "all second highest date"?

Comment: you want to fetch the second highest date for each music right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think I have the answer.
Please check this:

```
SELECT tbl.ID, tbl.UID, tbl.MUSIC, tbl.DATE
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MUSIC,
       Substring_index(Substring_index(gdate, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS sec_date
FROM   (SELECT MUSIC               ,
               GROUP_CONCAT(DATE order by DATE desc separator ",") AS gdate
        FROM   tbl
        GROUP  BY MUSIC) t1
) AS tbl2
  ON tbl.MUSIC=tbl2.MUSIC
    AND tbl.DATE=tbl2.sec_date
```

First of all I've created GROUP_CONCAT on DATE, ordered by desc, so I can use `Substring_index` to get the second `DATE`, and of course, grouped everything by MUSIC,
so the dates are grouped for respective MUSIC category. 
Then I wrote the actual query to get the results, with join to derived table so I ensure that I get correct row for that particular `MUSIC` AND `DATE`.

And here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3140f/65)

**UPDATE**

If you want to filter further by UID, just add `WHERE` to inner query, like this:

```
SELECT tbl.ID, tbl.UID, tbl.MUSIC, tbl.DATE
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MUSIC,
       Substring_index(Substring_index(gdate, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS sec_date
FROM   (SELECT MUSIC               ,
               GROUP_CONCAT(DATE order by DATE desc separator ",") AS gdate
        FROM   tbl
        WHERE UID=1 -- add filter here
        GROUP  BY MUSIC) t1
) AS tbl2
  ON tbl.MUSIC=tbl2.MUSIC
    AND tbl.DATE=tbl2.sec_date
```

and updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48208/4)

Comment: Thanks! Solved this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

From this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd47a2/7

```
SELECT tbl.UID, tbl.MUSIC, MAX(tbl.DATE)
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UID, MUSIC, MAX(DATE) as DATE
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY UID, MUSIC) AS tbl2
  ON tbl.UID = tbl2.UID
    AND tbl.MUSIC = tbl2.MUSIC
    AND tbl.DATE = tbl2.DATE
WHERE tbl2.UID IS NULL
GROUP BY tbl.UID, tbl.MUSIC
```

It does not however have the ID, which if you want, then IMO, you need to use the above query as yet another join to the original table to get the ID.

Comment: sorry - should be LEFT JOIN

Comment: Same issue.(query result is null)

Comment: @user2055052 - the error was more core than than, see the sqlfiddle link in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query -

```
SELECT ID, UID, MUSIC, MAX(DATE) FROM TableName
WHERE DATE NOT IN (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TableName )
```

I think its something like finding second highest salary of employee - [**Example**](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but here's one way...

```
 SELECT a.* 
   FROM
      ( SELECT x.*
          FROM my_music x 
          JOIN my_music y 
            ON y.uid = x.uid 
           AND y.music = x.music 
           AND y.date >= x.date 
         GROUP 
            BY id
        HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
      ) a
   JOIN
      ( SELECT x.*
          FROM my_music x 
          JOIN my_music y 
            ON y.uid = x.uid 
           AND y.music = x.music 
           AND y.date >= x.date 
         GROUP 
            BY id
        HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
      ) b
     ON b.uid = a.uid
    AND b.music = a.music
    AND b.date <= a.date
  GROUP 
     BY id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

select id,music,[uid] from (select  row_number() over ( PARTITION BY id order by [date] desc) as rn
 ,id,music,[uid] from  table_name) a where rn  = 2  -- insted of 2 u can change to any number u want

Comment: There is no row_number() in mysql

Comment: sorry that is for sql server

Answer (score -2):

Try this

This is SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Music ORDER BY Date DESC) NO,
*
FROM UrTable) AS T1 WHERE no = 2
```

Comment: There is no row_number() in MySQL.

Comment: then why you had tagged SQL.

Comment: It is tagged MySQL here

Comment: recently you had chengged

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is not (to my knowledge) part of the SQL standard - although I agree that, for separate reasons, the SQL tag should not have been used. I've now removed it.

Comment: As the Microsoft page, it has nothing to do with MySQL nor the SQL standard (i.e., the ANSI standard)   Here is a copy of the ANSI SQL 92 standard: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt